# Azure Function PowerShell retrieve and parse HTTP POST trigger body

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am triggering an Azure Function from Azure Synapse and send a constructed string as the Body of the HTTP POST request.

I am trying to convert it to a PS object and then do something with the values - for some reason I fail however and the variables `region` and `environment` are empty:

```
2023-05-12T11:17:13Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: region: 
2023-05-12T11:17:13Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: environment:
```

I checked the input of the Synapse "Azure Function" component in the pipeline and the input is as follows:

```
{
    "functionName": "MyFunc",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {},
    "body": "{environment: 'q', region: 'de', delta: 'true'}"
}
```

I also used the content of the "body" and did Test/Run with custom body (copy-pasted it), but it fails.

Here is the PS code from my Powershell:

```
using namespace System.Net
param($Request)
$request_body = $Request.Body | ConvertFrom-Json

$region = $request_body.region
$environment = $request_body.environment
Write-Host "Loaded runtime config from request body."
Write-Host "region: $region"
Write-Host "environment: $environment"
```

If I do the following locally, it parsed it correctly:

```
PS > $a = "{environment: 'q', region: 'de', delta: 'true'}"
PS > $b = $a | ConvertFrom-Json
PS > $b
environment region delta
----------- ------ -----
q           de     true
PS > Write-Host $b.environment
q
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `$Request.Body.region`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work - it looks like it comes in as a string and thus cannot be referenced

Comment: Yes, that's true

Comment: That's because it's not. It is a string.

Comment: Can you try `$Request.RawBody | ConvertFrom-Json`?

Comment: Not the same, but similar result, output: `{environment: 'q', region: 'de', delta: 'true'}`  - but it is still not converted into an object in which I can reference `environment`

Comment: Note that JSON doesn't officially support single quotes for strings - only double-quotes are valid. Some parsers are more flexible, so YMMV if you use single quotes... https://www.json.org/json-en.html "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**, using backslash escapes. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already had the correct solution... problem was the outdated PS (`'6.*'`) version. After updating the `requirements.psd1` to `'az' = '9.*'`  it works now.

However, in the end I solved it by actually passing a JSON from Synapse into the HTTP body. What confused me there initially is that the JSON object shows up as a string in the logs but this is actually not correct. It remains an object.